# How can I resolve the BSOD with the STOP Code 0x0000007B?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Whenever I boot my Windows 7 computer, I get a blue screen of death with the following details:

```
A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent
damage to your computer. 

If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen, restart you
computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:

Check for viruses on your computer.
Remove any newly installed hard drives or hard drive controllers. Check your
hard drive to make sure it is properly configured and terminated. Run CHKDSK
/F to check for hard drive corruption, and then restart your computer. 

Technical Information: 

*** STOP: 0x0000007B (0xFFFFF880009A98E8,0xFFFFFFFFC000000D,0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000)
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it so I can boot my machine once again?

Comment: Have you tried running chkdsk /f ?

Comment: Try the steps here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976

Comment: @ct64116: I'm glad you didn't recommend `chkdsk /r`. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a Microsoft support article titled:

[Error message when you start a Windows 7 or Windows Vista-based computer after you change the SATA mode of the boot drive: "STOP 0x0000007B INACCESSABLE_BOOT_DEVICE"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976)

I'd recommend reading it.

Your post doesn't indicate attempting to run in safe mode.  Continuously press F8 while the computer boots and select "Safe Mode" to see if your computer will boot.  If it does, uninstall the offending device driver.  This should never happen with Windows 7 signed drivers though.